# akka cassandra persistence with java example

Tags: java, cassandra, persistence, akka

Using Java I am trying to test the akka cassandra persistentence using java. From the URL (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.0-RC3/java/persistence.html) I am trying to make the PersistentActorExample work with cassandra and I am running into the following problems.

I am using below mentioned application.conf. Do you guys have any java implementation sample that I could use to get started? The same code works fine leveldb. Currently we are on datastax 4.8. I am hoping it is an application.conf issue.

---

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2550
    }
  }

  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551",
      "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2556",
      "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552"]

    auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
  }

  persistence {
    journal {
      plugin = "cassandra-journal"
      # Comma-separated list of contact points in the cluster
      cassandra-journal.contact-points = ["dse-9042.service.consul"]
    }

    snapshot-store {
      plugin = "akka.persistence.cassandra.snapshot.CassandraSnapshotStore"
      # Comma-separated list of contact points in the cluster
      cassandra-journal.contact-points = ["dse-9042.service.consul"]
    }
  }

  akka.extensions = ["akka.cluster.client.ClusterClientReceptionist"]
  akka.actor.default-mailbox.stash-capacity=10000

}
```

In my project I am using the following maven dependency;

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-persistence_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-RC3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.krasserm</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-persistence-cassandra_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is the Error I am experiencing:

```
[INFO] [10/04/2015 16:52:40.906] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [10/04/2015 16:52:41.112] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2550]
[INFO] [10/04/2015 16:52:41.124] [main] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2550] - Starting up...
[INFO] [10/04/2015 16:52:41.186] [main] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2550] - Registered cluster JMX MBean [akka:type=Cluster]
[INFO] [10/04/2015 16:52:41.186] [main] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2550] - Started up successfully
[INFO] [10/04/2015 16:52:41.193] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2550] - Metrics will be retreived from MBeans, and may be incorrect on some platforms. To increase metric accuracy add the 'sigar.jar' to the classpath and the appropriate platform-specific native libary to 'java.library.path'. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar
[INFO] [10/04/2015 16:52:41.196] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2550] - Metrics collection has started successfully
[INFO] [10/04/2015 16:52:41.380] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2550] - Welcome from [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552]
Uncaught error from thread [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[ClusterSystem]
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: akka.persistence.cassandra.journal.CassandraJournal.akka$persistence$journal$WriteJournalBase$_setter_$persistence_$eq(Lakka/persistence/Persistence;)V
[ERROR] [10/04/2015 16:52:41.950] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(ClusterSystem)] Uncaught error from thread [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: akka.persistence.cassandra.journal.CassandraJournal.akka$persistence$journal$WriteJournalBase$_setter_$persistence_$eq(Lakka/persistence/Persistence;)V
    at akka.persistence.journal.WriteJournalBase$class.$init$(WriteJournalBase.scala:15)
    at akka.persistence.cassandra.journal.CassandraJournal.<init>(CassandraJournal.scala:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)
    at akka.util.Reflect$.instantiate(Reflect.scala:44)
    at akka.actor.NoArgsReflectConstructor.produce(Props.scala:357)
    at akka.actor.Props.newActor(Props.scala:259)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:587)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:460)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:482)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:282)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:223)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

    at akka.persistence.journal.WriteJournalBase$class.$init$(WriteJournalBase.scala:15)
    at akka.persistence.cassandra.journal.CassandraJournal.<init>(CassandraJournal.scala:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)
    at akka.util.Reflect$.instantiate(Reflect.scala:44)
    at akka.actor.NoArgsReflectConstructor.produce(Props.scala:357)
    at akka.actor.Props.newActor(Props.scala:259)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:587)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:460)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:482)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:282)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:223)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.`enter code here`java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the stable version of Akka `2.4.0` (you're using a Release Candidate), and also bump the dependency for the cassandra plugin to `0.4` [which was released last week](https://github.com/krasserm/akka-persistence-cassandra/issues?q=milestone%3A0.4%20is%3Aclosed) and supports Akka `2.4.x`.

The reason you're getting the error is that you have pulled in conflicting versions of Akka (it's Journal Plugin API), and Journal implementation. The Journal Plugin API was experimental in Akka 2.3 and was subject to change while making it stable in `2.4.x`. Since Akka `2.4.0` the Journal API is **stable** and will not change in breaking ways.

Comment: That worked thanks for the help. However, this runs into a problem when we use cassandra-driver-core:2.1.7.1 jar. It works fine with cassandra-driver-core:2.1.5 jar. We use the 2.1.7.1 driver for its pagination support but akka persistence is not working.

Comment: It actually worked fine with 2.4.0-RC3 but bump up to 0.4 version really helped the cause. I still need to figure out 2.1.7.1 driver issue.

Comment: Please use a stable version - 2.4.0 for example, not the RC builds :)

Comment: I guess one last, does my application.conf looks good? It always go to my local cassandra, but not to the configured 'dse-9042.service.consul'. I tried different other options but i see the tables only getting created only on the localhost.

Answer (score 1):

As I see from the [com.github.krasserm repo](https://github.com/krasserm/akka-persistence-cassandra/commit/404c284399cd5b36d22085a922324b8e225cd533) he use

**akka 2.3.11** with **com.github.krasserm 0.3.9**

but you use

**akka 2.4.0** with **com.github.krasserm 0.3.9**

Try to change the **akka** to the version **2.3.11**
or **com.github.krasserm** to the version **0.4**